# Firefox adblock plus. How to remove element instead hiding it?

Tags: firefox, adblock

So I have this rule

```
www.foobar.com##div.annotation
```

It hides the div great. But how do I remove `<div>`?

The element is an annoying annotation cookie/whatever on top with CSS attribute `position:fixed` so I see transparent bar on top of the page.

Comment: you can't. at least not with ABP. ABP blocks certain requests from occurring, and hides elements; it does not remove elements.

Comment: @FrankThomas so no even a chance to apply CSS rule `display:none`?

Comment: Ads can tell if they are hidden, so the ABP folks force the add off-screen so the site can't tell that you are using ad blocking software.

Comment: @FrankThomas I understand thanks. I am surprised that there is no such options to do it. I guess I need to say hi to greasemonkey.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/):, and create new script

```
 // ==UserScript==
// @name           bleh somthing
// @description    ---s
// @version        1.0
// @license        Public Domain
// @grant          none
// @include        http*://*.DOMAIN.com/*
// @include        http://www.DOMAIN.com/.*
// ==/UserScript==


rem = document.querySelector('.annotation');
rem.parentNode.removeChild(rem);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using tampermonkey. This script is for deleting videos instead of hiding them. The example is specific for one site, but by analogy it can be done on any.

```
let listDeletes = [
    "/chennal/somestuff1",
    "/chennal/somestuff2",
    "/chennal/somestuff3",
    "/chennal/somestuff4",
    "/chennal/somestuff5",
    "/chennal/somestuff6",
    "/chennal/somestuff7",
    "/chennal/somestuff8",
    "/chennal/somestuff9",
];

function delBoxes() {

    for (let i = 0; i < listDeletes.length; i++) {
        document.querySelectorAll(`li a[href^="${listDeletes[i]}"`).forEach(e => e.closest('li').remove());
    }
}
delBoxes();

const observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutation) {
    mutation.forEach(function (mutation) {
        if (mutation.addedNodes.length) {
            delBoxes();
        }
    })
});
const playlistWrapper = document.querySelector('#videoPlaylist');
observer.observe(playlistWrapper, {
    childList: true
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).